# Kendo UI Autocomplete event when the suggestion list doesn't open yet

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I'm using Kendo UI Autocomplete select. I want to handle some cases where the input value doesn't match the suggested ones so the dropdown wouldn't show up.
For example when my list contains :

```
values=[1xx,2xxx,3xx,4x,5xx]
```

When the user insert some value in textbox like 6 as a first digits in meanwhile an event will be triggered.
Is there any way using JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You could write some custom functionality on the `filtering` event of the Kendo Autocomplete control.

1. Firstly, you would need to check that the user has only input 1 character so far
2. Then iterate over the `dataSource` of the Autocomplete control
3. Check if the first character of any of the `dataSource` items match the input value - using a boolean to determine if `true` or `false`
4. Then use [`e.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to stop the Autocomplete control from carrying out any further functionality (if a match has not been found based on the input value)
5. And finally, trigger a close on the Autocomplete control (to cover the scenario where a user enters a value, removes it and enters another which is not a match)

All neatly packaged in a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/EdObo/2) which should just about cover it!